# HTML and CSS lopsided tables

Tags: html, css

Site: http://sebastiano.freehostia.com/

CSS: /style.css

I'm not overly sure what's going wrong with the positioning of the boxes here. The header has a large space below it and the two in the centre are lopsided. Could someone enlighten me as to what's causing it please?

Thanks!

Comment: what's going on is you're using tables in a non-semantic nature, and karma is catching up to you.

Comment: As in they're nested? I don't see anything inherently different about their properties.

Comment: -1 tables should NOT be used for layouts. Tables are for displaying TABULAR data... Use divs for layouts, tables for displaying data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a default margin on the `<form>` element which might be causing some display issues.  Maybe you can also use a universal selector reset and see what that changes to help diagnose the problem `*{margin:0;padding:0}` or better yet: Design semantically and avoid table-based layouts (especially nested tables) and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

My quick guess would be the h1 / h2's default margin messing with things

try adding:

```
h1,h2{
margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
```

And see if that changes anything

Comment: You could also add valign="top" to the td tag containing each left and right table, however as everyone above mentioned you should be using just css for layout and avoid tables